# Typeset sign similar to n choose k, but with curly braces

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

## Question

I am looking for a way to typeset two variables over each other similar to `\binom{n}{k}` or `{n \choose k}`. The only difference is that it should be surrounded in curly braces instead of round ones. Is there a proper way to do it?

## My workaround

I've already attempted working around this using the following approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    This is a text containing
    $\begin{cases}
        \begin{rcases}
            n \\
            k\\
        \end{rcases}
    \end{cases}$,
    my mathematical symbol.

    My binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ for comparison.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it is an *ugly* workaround. The braces and size of the font are too big, as seen compared to the properly typeset binomial. Additionally, there's a huge amount of space on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should construct it the same way [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\binom` uses `\genfrac{<ldelim>}{<rdelim>}{<width>}{<math style>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bracenom}{\genfrac{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{0pt}{}}

\begin{document}

My binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ for comparison with $\bracenom{n}{k}$.

\end{document}
```

Leaving the `<math style>` empty implies that the current math style will be used. You can also define `\dbracenom` to use `<math style>` = `0` and `\tbracenom` to use `<math style>` = `1`. Here are the similar definitions for `\binom`-and-friends:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\binom}{\genfrac()\z@{}}
\newcommand{\dbinom}{\genfrac(){0pt}0}
\newcommand{\tbinom}{\genfrac(){0pt}1}
```

`<width>` refers to the rule between the `<numerator>` and `<denominator>`.